# How can I reference an unnamed argument of a when expression?

Tags: switch-statement, kotlin

I have a [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) that looks something like this:

```
when(foo.toString()){
    ""       ->'A'
    "HELLO"  ->'B'
    "GOODBYE"->'C'
    else     ->foo.toString()[0]//problematic method call duplication
}
```

Now, I don't want to call `foo.toString()` twice, but I also want this to remain a single expression. Is there a convenient way for me to access the value I passed into the when expression in its else block, such as the `it` or `this@` syntax found elsewhere in the language?

I'm currently using the following work-around:

```
with(foo.toString()){
    when(this){
        ""       ->'A'
        "HELLO"  ->'B'
        "GOODBYE"->'C'
        else     ->this[0]
    }
}
```

But this introduces another block, and is less readable than I'd like. **Is there a better solution?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin when() local variable introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102797/kotlin-when-local-variable-introduction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the when block there's no variable specified, but you can use the [`let()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) function for a similar behavior which might be a little better than your workaround, but behaving the same.

```
foo.toString().let{
    when(it){
        ""       ->'A'
        "HELLO"  ->'B'
        "GOODBYE"->'C'
        else     ->it[0]
    }
}
```